# Continue QXmlStreamReader on invalid elements

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qt5, qxmlstreamreader

Is it possible to make `QXmlStreamReader` robust against "small" XML document errors? For instance, I want to tolerate elements which have multiple attributes with the same name.

Regards,

Comment: I suppose an XML document with "small" errors is no more an XML document. I think `QXmlStreamReader` won't be able to read it.